# Nginx: location for subfolder

Tags: php, regex, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I want to move my root project to subfolder.

My current config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

And current project structure as expected:

```
/var/www/public
 ﹂index.php
```

---

The problem is to rewrite locations `~ \.php$` and `/` with new variable of subfolder (project name).

```
/var/www/new-project/public
 ﹂index.php
```

I've tried to rewrite locations but it didn't work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    # root /var/www/public;
    root /var/www;

    location ~ ([a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.]+)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^$1(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~/([a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.]+)$ {
        alias /var/www/$1/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

I think second location is pretty valid but I can't get how to rewrite it for `\.php$` ending.

Comment: You don’t need to change rewrite rules, only the ‘root’ variable, the rest remains the same.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, thank you for the answer. Actually, it worked out. But if I have more than one project subfolders in my root and I want to pass request by variable?

Comment: On that case, of course, you will need to do variable extraction and perform routing based on it.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Thanks, I know, that's why I'm here. I've tried in different ways but with no result.

Answer (score 0):

Found some overcome for this problem:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/;

    location / {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ /([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/(.+\.php$) {
        alias /var/www/$1/public/$2;
        # try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/$1/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$1/public/$2/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ {
        alias /var/www/$1/public/;
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;s
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

But the only one disadvantage of this approach that you can not use `try_files` with the `alias`.